# Updating memcached...will the data be flushed?

Tags: memcached

I know if you restart memcached the data is lost. What about when an update happens? I am not 100% sure even how to do an update, but I think yum will do it automatically and it would be very bad if the data was flushed on update.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the service will be restarted when the package is updated.

Unless you have something running `yum update` automatically, you can control when the update happens; schedule it for off-hours when the rebuilding of cache won't hurt too much.

Comment: I am using memcache for php sessions so I wouldn't want to do a restart at any point. Is there a way to keep the data?

Comment: @ChrisMuench Not that I know of.  I'd recommend [Redis](http://redis.io/) instead if you need data persistence and/or replication.